# Game Center for my iPhone Game

Tags: app-store-connect

I am developing an iPhone game, and I will implement Game Center in it.

Apparently, I need to do some configuration with my application in iTunes Connect first. Therefore I have to "create" my application in the iTunes Connect page, right? But, how do I do that without getting Apple's staff review my app since I am still working on it?

I tried making a new app like normal, but it asks me for a bunch of stuff like screenshots etc, but I have none to offer in the first place...

Comment: I can't because it requires Game Center to be finished. And Game Center can't work without app configuration in iTunes Connect. However, someone else already answered me, so fear not.

Comment: @Omega : Could u share the answer with us as i to have the same thing to do.

Comment: @Srinivas: I already answered.

Comment: @Omega : Could you kindly Provide the link..

Comment: @Srinivas: I answered this question (look below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. It seems they won't even review it if there is no binary uploaded yet.